# 4 displays of seven-segments to countdown automatically

Tags: hdl

I need help in display module and project module.

In this project, you will program the 4 displays of seven-segments to countdown automatically from (9999) to (xxxx) where xxxx is your last four number in your ID (for example, the initial value of the 4 displays is 9999 and my ID is (200412320), the counter will start countdown to reach {2320}). In addition, the pulse generator module will be used to generate a pulse where this pulse will reset the 4 displays to the initial value (9999) and the counter automatically will start countdown to (xxxx).

[image]

Comment: While homework questions are allowed you really need to show some effort in trying to answer the question yourself, we can then help when you get stuck. If you do not know how to make a counter go from 9999 to 2320, then start with a simpler upcounter, it should not be too hard to find an example of a verilog counter on the internet. Update the question via an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33973138/edit) when you have tried this.

Comment: Is this verilog or vhdl ? could you add the respective tag so users know what language your using.